# Бот не видит свои же сообщения в канале

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.channel_post_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def test(message: types.Message):
    print('message in channel detected')
```

Когда я, от своего имени отправляю сообщение в канал - бот его видит
Когда бот, от своего имение отправляет сообщение в канал - то этот же бот, его не видит

Comment: Эмм, а почему он должен его видеть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сделано умышленно. Представьте, что было бы если бот видел свои сообщения и реагировал на них.

1. Бот написал сообщение
2. Бот увидел новое сообщение от себя же (отправленное в 1 пункте), и ответил на него
3. Бот увидел новое сообщение от себя же (отправленное в 2 пункте), и ответил на него
4. Бот увидел новое сообщение от себя же (отправленное в 3 пункте), и ответил на него

Думаю, закономерность вы поняли. По итогу бот разговаривал бы сам с собой

**UPD**

Если вам нужно знать, какое именно сообщение отправил бот

```
message_from_bot = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Это сообщение отправил бот")
message_id = message_from_bot.message_id # теперь в переменной message_id у вас id сообщения, которое отправил в бот. Сохраняйте его и используйте как и планировали
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ
Просто нужно,сохранять каждый айди сообщения в канале,что через какое то время - удалить

Comment: Дополнил ответ, думаю это то, что вам и нужно